# How do I get started from reading SharePoint list information from outside of SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint

We have a SharePoint subscription and an Azure subscription. I want to make a web app that is hosted in Azure, but the database for the app would basically be SharePoint lists. I'm looking up documentation on how to do this, but I'm just finding how to make "web parts" and they keep assuming I want to build my website inside SharePoint rather than outside.

How do I access a user's SharePoint lists from outside of SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

The easy part is the request for data. Use the SharePoint REST API. The harder part is authentication. How is the Azure app related to the SharePoint app? Same user login?

A sample REST call for select columns from a list:

```
https://yourDoamin/sites/yourSite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('My List')/items?$select=Title,Price,Qty
```

The REST API also support filtering and sorting along with insert, update and delete.

A filter example:

```
https://yourDoamin/sites/yourSite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('My List')/items?$select=Title,Price,Qty&$filter=Title eq 'Toys'
```

If you would like to experiment with the REST API from your SharePoint site, I have "REST tester" you can add to a Content Editor Web Part.

https://github.com/microsmith/SharePointRESTtester

Comment: When accessing my Azure portal, I sign in using the same account as my SharePoint credentials, which is an organization account. All of us use Office 365 in my organization, and they are my target audience. (I'm making an internal app.) So yes, the same user login. Does this make things easier?